# Where to tell Qt Creator to search for header files for auto-complete

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, qt-creator

I am writing a C++ program in Qt Creator in Ubuntu, which links to a third-party library. I have downloaded this package through aptitude to get the header and library files. In my CMakesLists.txt, I tell the compiler how to search for these files. However, how can I tell Qt Creator where to look for the header file during code editing? As it stands, my program will compile, but auto-complete does not work because Qt Creator does not know yet where the files I have #included are located on my system; it only knows after looking at CMakesLists.txt.

Comment: Why do you use cmake instead of qmake?

Comment: I have just been advised to by some others due to its compatibility with projects created outside of Qt Creator.

Comment: You can use Qt projects outside of QtCreator too (using qmake), but I don't think that QtCreator parses CMakeLists.txt

Comment: Add the ``INCLUDEPATH+=/usr/lib/whatever`` to your .pro file. This way qmake should find the correct path and qtcreate should index the files for autocompletion. Not sure if this will hurt your cmake.

Answer (score 0):

QtCreator needs to run cmake in order to get that information.

When you open the project it prompts you to run cmake.